# Non-english parameter for argparse

Tags: python-3.x, django, encoding, argparse

Python 3.7.9

Ubuntu 20.04

I am extending django 3.1 management command functionality and added arguments parser to one of my commands like this:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('-c',
                            '--clients',
                            nargs='*',
                            help='list of clients to handle')
```

manage.py COMMAND -h

```py
  -c [CLIENTS [CLIENTS ...]], --clients [CLIENTS [CLIENTS ...]]
                        list of clients to handle
```

*The trouble is* that I when I try to pass a non-english parameter like this:

```py
manage.py download_feeds -c ЖЫВТОНЕ
```

and handle the argument like that:

```py
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        if options['clients']:  # parameters are specified
            for param in options['clients']:
                print(str(param))
```

it prints me ��������������

**How to handle it properly? So I can get ЖЫВТОНЕ instead of messed up characters?**

Comment: Likely a problem with your terminal in particular. Can it properly handle Unicode? If so, in what encoding? What terminal is it?

Comment: @deceze ubuntu 20.04 standard terminal echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

Comment: forgot to say I use it in docker but anyway

Comment: also 
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)'"
prints me encoding:
UTF-8